# How can I speed this SUM query up?

Tags: mysql

Im using the query below to calculate the the top 5 expenses per individual company and sorting them desc. Currently the table has about 3 million rows and takes about 8 seconds to properly execute. Im looking for a way to speed this up.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(cost) as sumw, 
    company FROM cost
WHERE 
   datetime BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-12-01'
GROUP BY company
ORDER BY sumw desc
LIMIT 5;
```

datetime has an index.

EXPLAIN:

```
1   SIMPLE  cost    NULL    ALL datetime    NULL    NULL    NULL    3204715 50.00   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

CREATE

```
CREATE TABLE `cost` (
  `id` bigint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cost` bigint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `datetime` (`datetime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3335830 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: add hardware; or generate the totals daily/hourly in advance of the query.  The SQL looks to be as efficient as it can be.  Maybe cast the strings to dates so it doesn't have to implicitly do it but I can't imagine that will gain you much.  Outside of MySQL I might suggest a materialized view w/ a periodic refresh, but MySQL doesn't have them.

Comment: It's customary when asking for SQL performance help to show the table definitions involved, including indexes. It's also a good idea to show the output of `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: added info @O.Jones

Answer (score 1):

A compound index on your `cost` table on `(datetime, company, cost)` may be able to improve the performance of this query.   It's worth a try, especially if the `cost` table has lots of other columns not involved in this query.

Notice something in your query.

```
 datetime BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-12-01'
```

retrieves all the rows with values from 1-Oct-2016 midnight to 1-Dec-2016 midnight **inclusive.**  You may want

```
datetime >= '2016-01-01' AND datetime < '2016-12-01'
```

if you're trying to handle data for October and November. This second formulation is no less efficient at using your index than the first formulation.

Comment: The query is being used properly. Phone dates where added for this question.

Comment: Adding indexes reduced it by 2 seconds

Comment: first add a composite index to speed up the query **ALTER TABLE `cost` add key idx_date_company  (`datetime`,`company`);** and test again. please post the new EXPLAIN

Answer (score 1):

Your query is calculating result as per company so it needs an index on company column.

```
ALTER TABLE cost ADD INDEX(company);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: With respect, this is incorrect. A MySQL query can (as of late 2016) only exploit a single index. And the dominating part of this questioner's query is the range search on the `datetime` column.